# Arranging icons inside a folder on Windows wherever I want

Tags: windows-7, windows

Is there any way to arrange icons in a Windows folder wherever I want?

I have to switch resolutions many times a day for work and my icons on the desktop are always being messed around. I wanted to have a personal folder where I can arrange my icons in the places I want (i.e. I want to put one in the top-left corned, I want to put another one in the right-top corner, etc..)

I'm targeting Windows 7 x64 or Windows 8

Comment: Desktop can be managed with [fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/) but software recommendations are generally not suitable for [Superuser](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: It's great but it doesn't allow me to disable "auto-arrange" inside fences. If it had it, I would buy it

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://superuser.com/questions/455654/windows-7-icon-management-when-commonly-changing-screen-resolutions)

Comment: you might want to try http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/ but i am not sure if it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Windows 7 uses a new Explorer control which doesn't implement disabling of atosorting. Here is a statement from a Developer of the Shell Team from Windows:

http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/813020-rearrange-folders-in-the-user-folder/?p=591458464#entry591458464

> "To help clarify, this isn't something which was actively removed,
>   however, Windows 7 includes a brand new view control for items in the
>   Explorer. Given time constraints, certain functionality **that was
>   deemed lower priority wasn't able to be implemented in the new
>   control.**"

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called PaperPort that lets you arrange thumbnails of all kinds of documents on a desktop for each folder.  I like to use it to put "piles" of documents or photos next to each other as if they were on an actual table.  I can arrange them anywhere I want, except I can't make stacks on top of each other like real papers.  Stacking PDFs can combine 2 documents into one. It can show thumbnails for many more types of documents than windows explorer.  You can decide which folders you want to include in it and all the folders can be viewed on the side to help you pick which folder you want to view.  The folders can even be given different colors.  This is one of my favorite programs for more than 10 years.  I would not want to be without it.